# Полоскает или полощет?

Tags: грамматика

Здравствуйте!

Сразу прошу меня извинить за орфографические ошибки. Мы с мужем выросли за границей,  но нам очень важно сохранить правильный русский язык.

Недавно у нас возник спор. Какое слово правильно: "полоскает" или "полощет".

Буду рада ответу.

Спасибо.

Яна

Answer (score 5):

Это две параллельные формы. Обе правильные. Полощу и полощет - нейтральное, полоскаю и полоскает – разговорное. Подробности [**здесь**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_10).